# PHP 5.6.10 - preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 100

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-framework2, preg-match

I've following regular expression configured in ZendFrame work routing

```
'constraints' => array(
 'controller' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
 'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
 'dashname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]*',
 'formatter' => '[a-zA-Z]*'
 )
```

throwing error
**Warning**:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 100 in **app\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment.php** on line **370**

Issue seems to be with 'dashname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]*',

Same code works in PHP 5.4 version but not in PHP5.6 version, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In class `-` is a range operator you need to escape it with `\`

`[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\s]`